# Solving for $a$, $b$, $c$ in $x=\cos a\sin b\sin c-\sin a\cos c$, $y=\sin a\sin b\sin c+\cos a\cos c$, $z=\cos b\sin c$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

How can I solve this system, to find $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$?

$$\begin{aligned}
x & = \cos\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma - \sin\alpha\cos\gamma \\
y & = \sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma + \cos\alpha\cos\gamma \\
z & = \cos\beta\sin\gamma
\end{aligned}
$$

In other words, I want to rewrite it like:

$$\begin{aligned}
\alpha & = \dots  \\
\beta & = \dots \\
\gamma & = \dots 
\end{aligned}
$$

($x$, $y$ and $z$ are known)

Is there any online tool that could do it for me? Wolfram alpha doesn't handle.

Comment: Anything special about $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ ?

Comment: In fact it does [Try it](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvJDooNaU0OTW6OlHB1lbBOb84uiJWITgzL7oSQlXFKuiCGUBhkGxVrI5CEkgpVAxVqTbMBJjSZJipcDW1OtUVOpU6VbWxsf//AwA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici They represent the yaw, pitch and roll of a rotation, I want to know them so I can make a rotation

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin What is this crazy stuff that it outputted? Where is the result?

Comment: @Kiosto : That is the output.  There are many, many cases.

Comment: Also, the inverse is not unique.  For instance, with $(x,y,z) = (0,0,-1)$, the two infinite families of solutions are $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \in \{(\pi + 2 \pi k_1, 0 + 2 \pi k_2, 3\pi/2 + 2 \pi k_3) : k_1, k_2, k_3 \in \Bbb{Z} \} \text{ and}$ $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \in \{(\pi + 2 \pi k_1, \pi + 2 \pi k_2, \pi/2 + 2 \pi k_3): k_1, k_2, k_3 \in \Bbb{Z} \} \text{.}$  You give no hints how you want these ambiguities resolved.

Comment: Uniqueness is definitely not plausible here. It is true that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ so this a system with 3 unknowns, but only two equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I had a way to solve the problem.

For brevity, i wrote the equations as
$$c(\alpha ) s(\beta ) s(\gamma )-c(\gamma ) s(\alpha )-x=0 \tag 1$$
$$c(\alpha ) c(\gamma )+s(\alpha ) s(\beta ) s(\gamma )-y=0 \tag 2$$
$$c(\beta ) s(\gamma )-z=0 \tag 3$$
$$c(\alpha )^2+s(\alpha )^2-1=0 \tag 4$$
$$c(\beta )^2+s(\beta )^2-1=0 \tag 5$$
$$c(\gamma )^2+s(\gamma )^2-1=0 \tag 6$$ where $c(t)=\cos(t)$ and $s(t)=\sin(t)$.

May be obvious : squaring $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$ and summing gives $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$; if this is not the case, end of the problem.

Now, I started eliminating one at the time the variables. This gives
$$s(\beta )=\frac{c(\gamma ) s(\alpha )+x}{c(\alpha ) s(\gamma )}$$
$$c(\gamma )=y c(\alpha )-x s(\alpha )$$
$$c(\beta )=\frac{z}{s(\gamma )}$$
$$s(\gamma )=\pm\sqrt{2 x y c(\alpha ) s(\alpha )+x^2 c(\alpha )^2+y^2 s(\alpha )^2+z^2}$$and the final equation is
$$x(1+c(2\alpha))+y s(2\alpha))=0$$ that is say
$$x (1+\cos (2 \alpha ))+y \sin (2 \alpha )=0$$ Excluding the trial $\alpha=\pm \frac \pi 2$, this leads to
$$\alpha=\pm \cos ^{-1}\left(\pm\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)$$ Going backward, we have the solutions for $\beta$ and $\gamma$.